# QMutex::lock: Deadlock detected in thread 0xfe8(Main Thread ?)

Tags: multithreading, qt, thread-safety

I am running my Program in GDB. My Program needs to create 16 threads for its work. and all these works fine. at the end I get the Error `QMutex::lock: Deadlock detected in thread 0xfe8`
here is the GDB Output

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\dgrfb.run\client/DGRFB.exe
[New thread 4076.0xfe8]
[New thread 4076.0x368]
warning: >> Socket State Changed:  QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState
warning: >> Socket State Changed:  QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState
[New thread 4076.0x4b8]
warning: >> Socket State Changed:  QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState
[New thread 4076.0x49c]
warning: Rect Area 0 2 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d5220)
warning: Rect Area 0 3 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d5548)
warning: Rect Area 1 0 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d5870)
warning: Rect Area 1 1 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d5b98)
warning: Rect Area 1 2 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d5ec0)
warning: Rect Area 1 3 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d61e8)
warning: Rect Area 2 0 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d6510)
warning: Rect Area 2 1 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d6838)
warning: Rect Area 2 2 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d6b60)
warning: Rect Area 2 3 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d6e88)
[New thread 4076.0x540]
warning: Rect Area 3 0 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d71b0)
warning: Rect Area 3 1 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d7568)
warning: Rect Area 3 2 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d7cc0)
warning: Rect Area 3 3 DG::UpdateThread(0xa0d7fe8)
[New thread 4076.0x670]
[New thread 4076.0x6dc]
[New thread 4076.0x674]
[New thread 4076.0x3ac]
[New thread 4076.0x684]
[New thread 4076.0x434]
[New thread 4076.0x44c]
[New thread 4076.0x7e8]
[New thread 4076.0x408]
[New thread 4076.0x7e0]
[New thread 4076.0x42c]
[New thread 4076.0x814]
[New thread 4076.0x6f8]
[New thread 4076.0x8a4]
warning: QThread(0x3d58d8) tick
warning: Rect #  0 0 100 56
warning:                 Unmatched true
warning:                 Updating  0 0
warning: QMutex::lock: Deadlock detected in thread 0xfe8
```

Now Which thread `0xfe8` is ? Is it the Main Thread ?
First I thought I've called the same `mutex.lock()` twice. or `func_a()` and `func_b()` are using the same mutex. thats causing the deadlock. But Not found any of such scenario.So Wheare to startthe investigation ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer which thread is causing the dead-lock. However as a rule of thumb try to use [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmutexlocker.html) to avoid dead-locks as much as possible. This way your mutext will be unlocked automatically.

Comment: Ya I am using `QMutexLocker` in most of the Places. and Taking a Close look on gdb output `[New thread 4076.0xfe8]` on First Line (see above) and `QMutex::lock: Deadlock detected in thread 0xfe8` at the end. Does it mean the main thread is in deadlock ? Hope I am able to make clear why I am focusing on `0xfe8` any clue ?

Comment: according to this output 0xfe8 is the first thread created. so yes it is the gui thread (main thread) that detected the deadlock

Comment: warning: QThread(0x3d58d8) tick part means that another thread has run and locked something which is also required by the main thread. the main thread blocks and deadlocks at this point.this is what i understand from this output.

Comment: Thats the `qDebug()` written in the `UpdateThread::tick()` `UpdateThread` is a `QThread`. there are 16 `UpdateThread`s and all are *Instantiated* in `ClientSocket` which is a `QTcpSocket` when some specific message arrives over the socket.and `tick()` is called every `t ms` through a timer set in the `threads`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this message when I tried to lock a mutex twice from the same thead. Making the `QMutex` [recursive](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qmutex.html#RecursionMode-enum) fixed it.